# How do I highlight code in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, highlight

When I'm writing python script using pycharm, I quite often want to highlight a piece of code that I'm working on. e.g., at teh end of the day so I can find it quickly the next day, or if i want to examine another piece of code then return quickly to the section I was working on.

If I was writing a Word document, for example, I might temporarily highlight the text so I can find it quickly.

Is it possible in pycharm to use a temporary highlight or mark up in the code?

Comment: You could add `#TODO ==== something ====` comments in the code and it will look something like this: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/06/working-with-todo-in-pycharm/. That can help you know where you last left off.

Comment: That's got it. thanks

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer too. Can you mark either of the two answers to give closure to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just add an answer instead of only having the comment available. That way the question can be closed.

In your Python code, prior to your ending the day, go to the line that you want to mark and type in a comment like such:

```
#TODO ======= leaving for 3/Oct/2017 =======
```

PyCharm will highlight TODOs. You can also look for TODOs easily. There's an article about TODOs written by JetBrains that might help also: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/06/working-with-todo-in-pycharm/

Previous answer of bookmarks is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in looking at JetBrains bookmarks, which let you, as its name implies, bookmark code for ease of access later down the line.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-bookmarks.html